# trying to capture first name from user

Tags: java

Trying to capture the first name of the user. I've searched high and low on how I can only accept the alphabet. Trying to loop this code block so it won't move on until only alphabet characters have been entered.

FYI, I'm very new to Java, any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class nameCollect {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    boolean test = true;
    String firstName;

    do {
      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.print("what is your first name? ");
      try {
        firstName = in .next();
        if ( in.hasNext("[A-Za-z]*")) {
          System.out.println("testing this out ");
        }
      }catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("invalid");
        in.next();
        test = true;
      }
    }while(test=false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class nameCollect {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter your first name ");
    String firstName = in .nextLine();
    while (!firstName.matches("[a-zA-Z]+$")) {
      System.out.println("invalid, please enter your name again");
      firstName = in .nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(firstName); in .close();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is this code? If it's an answer to your own question please [explain what the code does](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) and how it solves the problem.